# TypeError: Cannot add property x, object is not extensible

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am having trouble switching a boolean observable using a MobX action. The message seems to indicate that I'm trying to add a property when I'm just trying to switch it from false to true:

```
TypeError: Cannot add property text_copied_message, object is not extensible
src/stores/ui_store.js:54
  51 | }
  52 | 
  53 | change_copy_message_state () {
> 54 |     this.text_copied_message = true;
```

Here is the action:

```
change_copy_message_state () {
    this.text_copied_message = true;

    window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.text_copied_message = false;
    }, 5000);
}
```

This is the component code calling the action:

```
<CopyToClipboard text={ui_store.final_text_message}>
    <Button
        size='huge'
        color='orange'
        onClick={ ui_store.change_copy_message_state }
    >
        Copy Text and Open Social Media Sites in New Tabs
    </Button>
</CopyToClipboard>
```

Can anyone tell what is causing the issue?

Comment: How are you making `change_copy_message_state()` into an action? Also probably need to call `runInAction()` inside the timeout and set value inside that

Comment: Here is the decorate function I'm using: decorate(UiStore, {
    text_copied_message : observable,

    change_copy_message_state : action
});

Comment: Right and actions in Mobx either get decorated or call mobx `action()`

Comment: My mistake, comment above has been edited

Comment: Try using runInAction since the timeout is asynchronous

Comment: `window.setTimeout(() => { runInAction(()=> this.text_copied_message = false },5000)`

Comment: Is there a syntax error in that code? I'm getting a red lint when I use it but it looks correct to me. I also imported runInAction so it's not that. To sidestep the issue I just removed the settimeout, but the error is the same when using this:     change_copy_message_state () {
            this.text_copied_message = true;
    }

Comment: is `this.text_copied_message` defined before you try to set it in the action?

Comment: Yes, it is initialized as true

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem and I solved by converting the function to an arrow function, so in your case:

```
change_copy_message_state = () => {
    // ...
}
```

This way `this` is bound to the object. Alternatively, when decorating it, use `action.bound`.

Reference: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html